# About a result of ms ssim

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing

[image]

The above formula is from https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1292216, the paper of ms-ssim.

I calculated ms-ssim between two dummy images with this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

toy_1 = tf.cast(
                tf.random.uniform((2, 5, 256, 256, 1), 0, 2, dtype=tf.int32), 
                tf.float32
            )

toy_2 = tf.random.uniform((2, 5, 256, 256, 1), 0, 1, dtype=tf.float32)

tf.image.ssim_multiscale(toy_1, toy_2, max_val = 1.0)
```

(2, 5, 256, 256, 1) -> (batch, scales, height, width, channel).

So toy_1 had values of 0 or 1, toy_2 had values of range 0-1.

The result was:
[image]

The question is, **why the result has 5 values per batch?**
I thought that the result's shape would be (2, 1) instead of (2, 5), because product symbol is in the formula.

**What did i miss?**

Answer (score 0):

You should not include a `scales` dimension in your inputs. The downsampling operations are already included in `tf.image.ssim_multiscale`. All dimensions except the last three are treated as batch dimensions.